# Javascript code protection at Windows store app

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I will try to make Windows Store App using Javascript.I wonder safety of javascript code.Can anybody who use the app can reach javascript codes as web pages ? If javascript codes are not protected,is there a way to make it not reachable by users?

Answer (score 0):

When a Windows Store app written in JavaScript is installed on a machine, then its source code is basically sitting there. So anyhow, it is reachable for users.

But you can use whatever minification or obfuscation techniques you already know for JavaScript to make it harder for users to read your source code.